# How is Google doodle Guitar implemented

Tags: javascript, html, google-doodle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What technology is used at the Google homepage (guitarstrings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293016/what-technology-is-used-at-the-google-homepage-guitarstrings)

Today is Les Paul's birthday. Google has this cool doodle to play the guitar.

I am wondering how it is implemented.

1. Does it use Javascript?
2. Does it use any HTML 5 feature?
3. How does it play sound?

Comment: How long did you spend trying to find out yourself? It seems that every interactive doodle gets their own question here these days. Seriously, they're not that complicated or amazing...

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate. Flash for audio, canvas for animation, CSS image for the background.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the Closure compiler and closure tools developed by google to simplify development. HTML5 features are used. There might be the use of flash, like their previous Pacman implementation (depended on Flash)